# ImplementedVersion is not accessible in exec:java target

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest

I have used this how2 to add the Version number to our produkt: http://www.christophkiehl.com/easy-way-to-display-your-apps-version-using-maven-and-manifest

when i now build a jar with `mvn assembly:single` i see the correct version.
But when i just run everything with `mvn exec:java` i get null...

what do i have to do that `App.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` does not return null when i just start the programm from the non-jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique that you have used to add version number works only when built as a jar.

A different way to achieve the same would be to have a properties file which gets updated with the project version during build, which in turn is read by your java code.

Say, you have a file `version.properties` in `src/main/resources`, which has an entry

```
product.version=${project.version}
```

In the place you call `App.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`, you read this property and display the contents.

This will work in both jar and non-jar case.

**Update:** You would need to update the pom to enable filtering for resources - essentially add a snippet like the below (refer [this](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) for details).

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: do i have to add something to my pom file to extract the version to this properties file or does not work automaticly?

Comment: @reox.  Updated the answer with required pom changes.